# Best resources for learning unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Over the last week or so I have been trying to learn how to unit test in Angular. But I have found my self asking a lot of questions on-line and dispit looking at the Angular doc's, Jasmine doc's and on-line blogs I am still feeling a little lost. Does anyone know some good resources for learning how to unit test? It doesn't have to be specific to angular I'm also interested in learning the theory or methods people use to unit test their projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321146530/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)

If you've never done or are curious about TDD, this is a great book to carefully walk you through learning how and why to do it.